# C# overriding methods in object declaration like in Java

Tags: java, c#, declaration, overriding

but I've been programming in Java so I know you can Override methods in Object's instantiation

```
        private MyObject myObject=new MyObject(){
             @Override
             public void myMethod(int args){
               .
               .
               .
             }
      }
```

can somebody show me how to do this in C# please.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so I know you can Override methods in Object's declaration

This isn't *object declaration* but *class instantiation*. And this feature doesn't exist in C# .

Therefore, you can only override polymorphic methods on class declarations:

```
public class A 
{
    public virtual void DoStuff() {}
}

public class B : A 
{
    public override void DoStuff() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Java where all instance methods a *virtual* ones, in C# you have to put `virtual` keyword *explicitly*:

```
   public class MyObject {
     ...
     // in order to be overriden in a derived class, base method should be 
     // explictly declared as virtual or abstract
     public virtual void myMethod(int args){
       ... 
     } 
     ...
   }
```

In C# `override` is a *keyword* as well, not just an attribute:

```
   // class can't be declared locally, but explictly
   public class MyOverridenObject: MyObject {
     ...
     // override is a mandatory keyword in the context
     public override void myMethod(int args){
       ... 
     } 
   }
```

Finally, C# doesn't allow implementing classes *locally*, so you have to declare the class *explicitly* (`MyOverridenObject` in the code above) and then use:

```
   // Finally, you can assign an overriden class to the private field
   private MyObject myObject = new MyOverridenObject();
```